# Retrofit interface deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, retrofit, jackson-databind

I have an a response object that always include response object as property and different types of values hence I have Interface in a class as a field, so that it would bring correct implementation based on some unique value identifier.

```
Could not execute the callcom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.opngo.nowos.nowos.api.response.DataResponse]: missing type id property 'operation' (for POJO property 'response')
 at [Source: (okhttp3.ResponseBody$BomAwareReader); line: 1, column: 180] (through reference chain: com.opngo.nowos.nowos.NowOSResponse["response"])
```

Here is my Interface

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "operation")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AuthResponse.class, name = "account_auth")})
public interface IResponse {
    ///
}
```

Here is one of the response objects that implements the interface mentioned above

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthResponse implements IResponse {

    @JsonProperty
    private final String accountID;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String authToken;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String language;
}
```

Here is main Response that have that interface that should bring correct response object

```
    public class NowOSResponse {

    @JsonProperty
    private final String operation;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String version;
    @JsonProperty
    private final IResponse response;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String status;

}
```

It looks like it does not look into the parent and searches for operation field in the AuthResponse which is of course empty since operation field is always present in parent and that parent have response -> AuthResponse ->CreateAccResponse and so on

Answer (score 0):

i would like to post a solution which hopefully will help you.

If you have a an object within the object that is always returning different properties you can approach with the following :

1)Create an abstract class for example MainResponse, that response will contain status and operation since that properties are constant

```
public abstract class MainResponse {

    @JsonProperty
    private String version;
    
    public abstract IResponse getResponse(); // so we declaring it abstract so that all the childrens have to override it in order to return specific interface realisation

}
```

Now we have to create a specific response body that should be return based on the api call.

```
@Getter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AuthResponse implements IResponse {

    @JsonProperty
    private String accountID;
    @JsonProperty
    private String authToken;

}
```

Now since json will expect response json property we must create an additional class that will extend the abstract class, which means we would have getResponse that needs IResponse as a return, and hence we have implement that interface in AuthResponse, we can simply conclude AuthResponse as composition object in a new let say NewResponse class and return it.

```
@Getter
public class NewResponse extends MainResponse {

    @JsonProperty
    private AuthResponse response;
}
```